# unable to install fr3d/ldap-bundle on symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

I try to install the bundle fr3d / ldap on symfony but it returns me an error

> http://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.13
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.12
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.11
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.10
>   .............
>    - don't install symfony/security v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
>       - don't install symfony/security v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
>       - don't install symfony/security v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
>       - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.
>   2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9].

.... since some time I find not the reason. **i use symfony 3.2** help me. Thank you